# How to fix the database returned no natively generated identity value

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I keep getting the error above whenever I am trying to save. I am using MySQL and Springboot with Hibernate. An incident occurred — production tables were restored. After this whenever there is action that calls .save() the error is thrown. It was worthy to note that the DBA administrator revoked DDL right from the user as a short-term strategy.

The tables have auto-increment in them and this is a sample of one of the models.

```
public class Pojo implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
```

I would not know what else could be causing the error. I have read through other similar problems, none is able to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when the tables were restored (possibly recreated), the id was not created to auto-increment and even as a primary key. So, I modified the columns and that fixed the issue.